# Past perfect and Past perfect continuous

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense, past-tense, past-perfect

Please explain to me which is the correct usage.

> Balu had worked in several other States when he decided to work in Kolkata.

Or

> Balu had been working in several other States  when he decided to work in Kolkata.

I think we should use past perfect continuous here but I'm not sure of it. Do we need any more context to decide this?

I've seen many explanations regarding this topic here and also on google, still unsure of which tense to use in which case.

We use the Past Perfect to show that something started in the past and continued up until another action in the past.

We use the Past Perfect Continuous to show that something started in the past and continued up until another time in the past for a time reference. And it can be used to talk about actions or situations that were in progress at a certain point of time in the past

Do we certainly need time reference to use past perfect continuous?

> If I replace "several other states" with a single state say Delhi shall I use past perfect continuous?
>
> And one more question is can we use past perfect when the time reference was given in the sentence like "Balu had worked in Delhi for 5 years when he decided to work in Kolkata"?

It's very confusing topic. Could you please shed light upon the subject and explain to me a simpler way about how to use these tenses?

Comment: Your first example is better for what you probably want to say, because it implies nothing about whether Balu worked in several other states *consecutively* or *concurrently*. Since Past Perfect Continuous implies recency and/or relevance to time of utterance, it much more strongly implies that what Balu had been doing (working in other states) represents a *single* activity. That's to say, your amended version would only be more appropriate if Balu's (one and only) previous occupation involved interstate work, not that he'd had a succession of different jobs in different states.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What if I replace "several other states" with a single state say Delhi? Now shall I use past perfect continuous? And one more doubt is can we use past perfect when the time reference was given in the sentence like "Balu had worked in Delhi for 5 years when he decided to work in Kolkata"? Please explain it.

Comment: @Anonymous, See my response to your comment on my answer.

Comment: @Anonymous: Even if it was just *one* other place, I'd guess most native speakers wouldn't bother with the more complex tense unless the *fact* of Balu having been working there somehow had relevance to his subsequent decision to work in Kolkata. But even then I think I'd be inclined to simply change your ***when*** to ***before*** and stick with the simple past. Unlike many non-native speakers, I'm not *looking* for opportunities to use complex tenses - quite the opposite in fact, since given the chance I tend to favour simple tenses wherever I can get away with them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree. But it's very important for us to learn about usage of all the tenses, not only tenses but whole grammar also.

Comment: @Anonymous: I didn't mean that you shouldn't learn about perfect and continuous verb forms, or *never* use them. Just that at your level (which is relatively advanced) it would probably help you more to think in terms of how you can *avoid* using a complex tense, rather seeking to *justify* it. Your example is a typical case where I don't think ***when*** works very well anyway. But if you change it to ***before*** the temporal sequence is obvious, and doesn't need to also be reflected by tense. So you can happily use simple past and forget about past perfect *and* past perfect continuous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't say that, by the way this is a "fill in the blanks" question for which I was given four options, all are past tense forms, and answer was given as past perfect is the correct usage. But I can't understand why it's the correct usage and why not past perfect continuous. So, I asked here to know the difference in usage of these two. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Anonymous: Any test which claims that past perfect is "correct" for the example you've given is simply a bad test (not just because of ***when*** rather than ***before*** and failure to provide simple past as the obvious option). *That's* why I often make the point that learners are being badly served by incompetent teachers and examiners. But I won't keep arguing here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I strongly agree with you. I felt the same in many instances. It happens with Everything( not only English). I had many instances of this type confusion in English but couldn't find anyone to clear this. Finally I found this site really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Multiple states**

We use a continuous verb-form to describe something that has been going on for some time.

If Balu had been going back-and-forth, back-and-forth between all these states for a long time, then a continuous tense is required.

If Balu worked first in one state, then in another state, then in another state, etc... working in all of the states (except maybe the last one) is completed, so a simple tense (in this case past perfect) is sufficient.

When in doubt, use the simplest tense that works: in this case, if he's not been going back-and-forth, it's past perfect.

**Single state**

> Balu had worked in Delhi when he decided to work in Kolkata
>         [---Delhi----][---Not Delhi--- decision]

At some time before he decided to work in Kolkata, Balu had worked in Delhi. He was not working in Delhi when he made the decision. Past perfect without **for**: completed.

> Balu had worked in Delhi for five years when he decided to work in Kolkata
>         [---Delhi for five years----decision]

Balu in worked in Delhi for five years and was still in Delhi when he made the decision. Past perfect with **for**: not completed.

> Balu had been working in Delhi when he decided to work in Kolkata
>         [---Delhi----][---not Delhi---- decision ]
>   or    [----------Delhi---------------decision-----]

Balu had worked in Delhi (and may have still been doing so) when he made the decision. Past perfect continuous, without **for**, possibly completed. This one is probably best avoided: it is ambiguous and so doesn't sound right.

> Balu had been working in Delhi for five years when he decided to work in Kolkata
>         [---Delhi for five years---- decision]

Balu had worked in Delhi continuously for five years, and was still doing so when he made the decision. Past perfect continuous with **for**, not completed.

**And just for completeness...**

> Balu was working in Delhi when he decided to work in Kolkata
>         [---Delhi----decision]

Balu had been working in Delhi for an unspecified time, and was still doing so, when he made the decision. Past continuous, not completed.

Note that you can't use **for** and **when** at the same time with past continuous.

> Balu was working in Delhi for five years ... past continuous
>   Balu worked in Delhi for five years ... past simple 
>         [---Delhi for five years----]      now

Balu had been working in Delhi for an unspecified time, but doesn't any more Past continuous or past simple with **for**.

Comment: What if I replace "several other states" with a single state say Delhi? Now shall I use past perfect continuous? And one more doubt is can we use past perfect when the time reference was given in the sentence like "Balu had worked in Delhi for 5 years when he decided to work in Kolkata"? Please explain it.

Comment: Ah, now that's a **completely** different question, and it's not suitable for a quick response in a comment.. Please edit your question and add this as a second part to your question, and then I will update my answer.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Anonymous: And I my answer.

Comment: I had doubts about past continuous and past simple with for-time phrase. Now it's clear.

Comment: Many of these cases aren't as cut and dry and you are making out. Especially, "Balu had worked in Delhi for five years when ...". It could be a uncompleted action and that might be the more natural interpretation, but it could also be completed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you could use either tense to convey the same meaning, but there are subtle differences.

Using the past perfect continuous tense, it could mean that Balu was working in multiple states *simultaneously* and that he was now also going to work in Kolkata.

> If I replace "several other states" with a single state say Delhi shall I use past perfect continuous?

Replacing "several other states" with "Delhi" doesn't change anything grammatically.

> And one more doubt is can we use past perfect when the time reference was given in the sentence like "Balu had worked in Delhi for 5 years when he decided to work in Kolkata"?

Yes, you can do that.

Now, if you want to make your sentences sound a little more natural, you might say:

> Balu had worked in several other states **before** he decided to work in Kolkata.
>
> Balu had **already** worked in several other states when he decided to work in Kolkata.

or even:

> Balu had **already** worked in several other states **before** he decided to work in Kolkata.

You are contrasting two ideas and these changes make that contrast more emphatic. They work with both tenses:

> Balu had been working in several other states **before** he decided to work in Kolkata.
>
> Balu had **already** been working in several other states when he decided to work in Kolkata.
>
> Balu had **already** been working in several other states **before** he decided to work in Kolkata.