# Past continuous or past perfect continuous

Tags: past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

I read the difference in a site and really makes me confused. Is it true?

Past continuous vs. past perfect continuous tense

Both of these can show a past action interrupted by another action. However, the major difference is this:

With the past continuous, the action continues after the interruption.

With the past perfect continuous, the action stops after the interruption.

In this example, which uses the past continuous tense, the cat continues to nap after the owner returns:

The cat was napping when its owner came home.

Whereas in this example, which uses the past perfect continuous tense, the cat was napping but stopped when the owner returned:

The cat had been napping when the owner came home.

Comment: I don't think we can tell whether the cat woke up when the owner returned or not.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting I think so too, but I read it in very famous site 

Comment: Both are right, but they mean different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past perfect and Past perfect continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103718/past-perfect-and-past-perfect-continuous)

Comment: So, what was this 'famous site'?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense/  at the end of this article, they talked about past continuous vs past perfect continuous, they wrote it